# Как запустить отдельно метод класса с измененным аргументом?

Tags: python-3.x, requests, pymongo

подскажите, пожалуйста, как вызывать отдельно метод класса с измененным аргументом ?

есть код, который проверяет валидность покупок, и в запросе валидности запрос принимает переменную со значением True / False, как можно реализовать вызов метода изменив переменную с True на False или обратно ?

```
import pymongo
import requests

class changeDataAndRecheck():
    def __init__(self, count, profile, status):
        self.count = count
        self.profile = profile
        self.status = status

    def input_infomation(self):
      # добавляем чек в базу

    def validate_check(self):
     id_all_offers_with_criteria = [71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88]
    id_list = []

    params = {'platform': 'google',
              'profileId': self.profile,
              'ignoreCriteria': self.status}

    response_avialibe_offer = requests.get('ссылка запроса', params=params)
    response = response_avialibe_offer.json()
    try:
        for k in response:  # находим все ид доступных оффер
            find_id = k.get('id')
            id_list.append(find_id)
        print(id_list)

        for id_all_el in id_all_offers_with_criteria:
            find_index = id_list.index(id_all_el)  # находим индекс оффера из ответа x используя ид оффера
            find_sucsess_offer = response[find_index]  # находим все тело оффера по найеднному индексу
            criteria_flag = find_sucsess_offer.get('criteriaValidated')  # вытягиваем значение поля criteriaValidate
            print(f'{id_all_el}:{criteria_flag}')
    except:
        print('ID not find')

run = changeDataAndRecheck(count, profile, status)
run.input_infomation()
run.validate_check()
```

Comment: так вроде, метод validate_check никаких аргументов не имеет. Что вы имеете в виду?

Comment: я передаю данные валидности (true/false - строковом виде) в переменную 'status'                    оттуда status передается в запрос `params = {'platform': 'google',
 'profileId': self.profile,
  'ignoreCriteria': self.status}`

Comment: вы хотите, что б при *некоторых!* вызовах значение бралось не из свойств объекта, а задавалось вами?

Comment: ага, либо же что то такое после выполнения кода 'if status == 'true':
    status = 'false'
    run.receck_criteria()'

Comment: а вот теперь не понял, почему просто так не сделать? `'if status == 'true': status = 'false'; else: status = 'true'` И что такое run.receck_criteria() - раньше такого не было?

Comment: Вы напишите в вопросе вашу проблему, оставив только то, что конкретной с ней связано. Будет всем проще понять.

Comment: дописал в метод класса запрос, хотел бы реализовать, чтоб этот метод выполнялся два раза с `'ignoreCriteria' == True и False`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def validate_check(self, ignoreCriteria=None):
     if ignoreCriteria is None:
          ignoreCriteria = self.status

...

    params = {'platform': 'google',
              'profileId': self.profile,
              'ignoreCriteria': ignoreCriteria}
```

если аргумент не задан, берется из свойств объекта.

но можете вызвать с любым вам нужным состоянием `obj.validate_check('True')`

Comment: спасибо вам большое, за ваш ответ :D